# ParticleCollision not working but trigger does work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a tornado that's a particle system made with a mesh that I made with Maya and shaders,
When I use the tornado it travels but doesn't show that anything has been hit.

[image]

The script is in the Particle Collision and the Enemy just in case

This is my particle collision

[image]

As you can see collision messages is ticked I even slowed down the tornado just in case that was causing the problem

Enemy collider is not in IsTrigger

The weird thing is that it does work when I tick the Trigger in Particle collision

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the object you are trying to hit have a `Rigidbody` component on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

So when I created the tornado mesh on Maya I did it on centimeters so after that it was scaled so I could see it in the game.

I gave up on the initial collision thing and decided to do it manually by script, after trial and error I got mad and put the collision target to 500 (don't ask I might be insane) or so then it sent a message.

Turns out what I was seeing on the inspector of the prefab was the mini Tornado all along so the collision circle was so small it was almost impossible to hit anything.